# Change Variable "Richtung" to 0 by pressing the down button

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I am using an Arduino Uno with 4 Buttons and I am trying to change the variable "Richtung" to 0 by pressing the down button. I programmed the other 3 and they worked perfectly.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_LEDBackpack.h>

Adafruit_8x8matrix matrix = Adafruit_8x8matrix();

int IO_BUTTON_UP = 4;
int AIO_BUTTON_MATRIX = 3;
int IO_BUTTON_DOWN = 5;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Matrix8x8");
  Serial.println("<Autor>");
  matrix.begin(0x70);
  matrix.setBrightness(1);
  pinMode(IO_BUTTON_UP, INPUT);
  pinMode(AIO_BUTTON_MATRIX, INPUT);
  pinMode(IO_BUTTON_DOWN, INPUT);
}

int richtung = 0;

void loop() {

  int valButtonMatrix = analogRead(AIO_BUTTON_MATRIX);
  if (digitalRead(IO_BUTTON_DOWN) == 2){
    richtung = 0;
  }
  if (valButtonMatrix > 600){ //Rechter Button
    richtung = 1;
  } else if (valButtonMatrix > 400) { //Linker Button
    richtung = 3;
  }
  if (digitalRead(IO_BUTTON_UP) == 1){
    richtung = 2; 
  }
}
```

Comment: "_I programmed the other 3 and they worked perfectly._" - yet, you haven't revealed the problem you have with the fourth.

Comment: digitalRead() returns a value of HIGH (1) or LOW (0); it should never return 2. analogRead() works only on the analog pins (for example A3 rather than 3), and should not be set up with a pinMode() call.

Comment: I got the answer, I just had to connect IO_BUTTON_DOWN to 7 instead of 5 because the Down button is connected with the 7th sensor